# Source control integration with Brackets

Tags: version-control, file-management, projects-and-solutions, adobe-brackets

How can a project in Brackets be configured to require file check-in in source control? Would that be a configuration made with whatever source control option you've chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official source control feature in Brackets, but there are a number of extensions that provide integration with source control.

[This Git extension](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git) is definitely a popular one, and it's very actively maintained. You can search for others either in Brackets (*File > Extension Manager*) or [online](https://brackets-registry.aboutweb.com/). There's at least one other Git extension and a Perforce extension as well.

I'm not sure what you mean by "require file check-in," though. Is there a specific action you want the tool to enforce somehow?

Comment: Maybe "require check-in" is reserved more for the source control tool. As in, I want to ensure the project still builds when new code is checked in. Does seem out of the scope of Brackets.

Comment: @MattSmith I believe the Git extension I linked to above will automatically warn you if any of the files you're trying to commit have lint errors. (Linting is extensible, so you can add things beyond the simple JSLint that's built in to Brackets). Hopefully that gets you halfway there, at least?

Comment: Thanks, ytpete! I gotta dig into that, sounds promising.